# Meteor crashing while building

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript

I am building a fairly rather simple Meteor project on Windows 8, and despite both re-installing meteor, and manually re-setting the library, after the app has run for a short time meteor crashes and will not restart. Meteor is also unable to run reset, and I haven't been able to identify exactly what it is that causes this arise in the first place. There is a consistent error I get from the ccorcos:swipe, but runtime errors should not be crashing meteor right?

I have tried changing/removing the files in .meteor/client.

My question is both to identify what could be causing this particular error (what does "stat" mean in this context? other error messages I have found have while searching have been far more useful) as well as generally if there is a faster way of hard resetting a meteor project than running meteor create proj_name in a new folder and manually moving over the source files.

The stacktrace is below.

The packages I use are

- meteor-platform
- insecure
- bevanhunt:leaflet
- mdg:geolocation
- accounts-facebook
- service-configuration
- less stevezhu:lodash
- ccorcos:swipe
- iron:router
- underscore
- coffeescript
- accounts-ui
- accounts-password

```
C:\Users\Fjafjan\Documents\GitHub\progress>meteor run
[[[[[ C:\Users\Fjafjan\Documents\GitHub\progress ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.

C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:245
                                                throw(ex);
                                                      ^
Error: EPERM, stat 'C:\Users\Fjafjan\Documents\GitHub\progress\.meteor\local\build\programs\web.browser\packages'
  at Object.Future.wait (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\
fibers\future.js:398:15)
  at Object.wrapper [as stat] (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\files.js:1350:24
)
  at C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\files.js:454:43
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_m
odules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
  at Object.files.cp_r (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\files.js:444:5)
  at C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\files.js:456:13
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_m
odules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
  at Object.files.cp_r (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\files.js:444:5)
  at C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\files.js:456:13
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_m
odules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
  at Object.files.cp_r (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\files.js:444:5)
  at Object.files.rename (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\files.js:1401:13)
  at Object.files.renameDirAlmostAtomically (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\fi
les.js:810:11)
  at [object Object]._.extend.complete (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\builder
.js:482:11)
  at C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\bundler.js:1933:13
  at C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\bundler.js:2147:20
  at C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\buildmessage.js:264:13
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\fiber-
helpers.js:115:14)
  at C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\buildmessage.js:257:29
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\fiber-
helpers.js:115:14)
  at C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\buildmessage.js:255:18
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\fiber-
helpers.js:115:14)
  at C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\buildmessage.js:246:23
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\fiber-
helpers.js:115:14)
  at Object.capture (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\buildmessage.js:245:19)
  at Object.exports.bundle (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\bundler.js:2040:31)

  at C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-app.js:554:24
  at time (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\profile.js:231:28)
  at Function.run (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\profile.js:377:12)
  at bundleApp (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-app.js:544:34)
  at [object Object]._.extend._runOnce (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-app
.js:591:35)
  at [object Object]._.extend._fiber (C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-app.j
s:821:28)
  at C:\Users\Fjafjan\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-app.js:402:12
```

Comment: Might be more useful if you filed this in [Meteor's windows issue](https://github.com/meteor/windows-preview)

Comment: done. Is this really the wrong place to ask a question like this though? Especially hard-resetting your meteor build without re-installing/making a new repo and copy-pasting.

Comment: I think it's fine -- there are [other very similar issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508933/enotempty-and-eperm-exceptions-while-bundling-meteor-application-on-win7) to this on Stackoverflow but this seems new. I just think the Meteor team would know better what the issue is.

Comment: [follow-up issue on github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4933), I can't find the original one.

Answer (score 2):

As I'm new to programming, I can't tell you why this happens, but I was having the exact same problem. If you install a package using meteor add (package) while you have your app open in a code editor, it causes the app to break. Try closing the editor and refreshing everything. It worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me. Closed my atom editor and restarted meteor.

Answer (score 0):

Kill the meteor processes and reset the project.

```
ps aux | grep meteor
kill -1 [PID_OF_METEOR_PROC]
cd /path/to/project/
meteor reset
```

Replace [PID_OF_METEOR_PROC] with the actual PID or run once for each PID, and use the correct path to your meteor project

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am building on a windows 8 system (which I wrote) so I cannot use this answer. I also tried to use meteor reset and killing the meteor system and this was not the solution (I think I wrote this in my original questions as well).

Comment: Sorry, you are completely right. I did not see that earlier.